# Can checkpoint flags be turned off?

Tags: forza-horizon-3

I just bought Forza Horizon 3 yesterday and am loving it so far but I'm wondering if there is a way to turn off checkpoint flags in races? I don't recall seeing anything related to checkpoints in the Difficulty settings but perhaps it's somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I've read [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gaming/what-to-play/forza-horizon-3-review/):

> As long as you keep within the checkpoints, it’s fair game.

**It sounds like the checkpoints are a core mechanic and not able to be turned off.** This is actually the source of a complaint in [this review](https://web.archive.org/web/20161201032441/http://darkzonereport.com/forza-horizon-3-review) (cached version, original link is actually dead):

> the checkpoint placement can be a little frustrating at points – where you’ll narrowly miss a checkpoint banner by inches and then be forced to restart the race – which breaks the sheer pace and momentum that Horizon champions everywhere else in the game.

Actually you're not forced to restart the race, your car position is just reset to a place before the missed checkpoint and you just go from there, *without* stopping the race.

Comment: Everything you've said seems to coincide with what I've been seeing (it's a core mechanic). I didn't know that since this is my entry into the series and checkpoints were supposedly present in FH2 as well. I will say that your second citation is incorrect...You are not forced to restart the race but you are set a few meters back from the checkpoint that was missed.